# "Client not ready yet" when adding splashscreenactivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, splash-screen

I want to add a splashscreen activity to my app.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2, Preview 3

I just modify my manifest, to add  in the new activity :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="me.youactive.hts.youactive">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="YouactiveSlidingMenu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here is my SplashScreenActivity.java

```
package me.youactive.hts.youactive;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // Obtain the sharedPreference, default to true if not available
    boolean isSplashEnabled = sp.getBoolean("isSplashEnabled", true);

    if (isSplashEnabled)
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //Finish the splash activity so it can't be returned to.
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
                // Create an Intent that will start the main activity.
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
    else
    {
        // if the splash is not enabled, then finish the activity immediately and go to main.
        finish();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
}
}
```

If I change my manifest, and put the  arround MainActivity, the application launches successfull

In my Run windows,I can see this message :

*adb shell am start -n "me.project.com.project/me.project.com.project.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..*

I had read in some similar question in SO that adding "android:exported="true" in  in Manifest could resolve this problem, but it won't in my case.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code. It is because your emulator/device is not ready. Try doing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` in AS terminal, then try again

Comment: I only run my app on my device, I never use any emulator.  I try to type your command, but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi connectivity could be reason for this error.

It might be a good idea to reconnect to your wifi before making any code related changes.